# Getting Bad Access error with iOS Annotations and Arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, exc-bad-access

The code below is for conducting search with `MKLocalSearch` and loading the results into an array.

This array gets passed to my `[self.mapView addAnnotations:annotations]` method. Everything works great until I try to dismiss this `viewcontroller` by tapping the back button (in my navigation bar for storyboards).

I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x4)`.  If I comment out the Show Pins section below the problem goes away (but of course I am now not loading my annotations).

Please help!

```
-(void)issueLocalSearchLookup:(NSString *)searchString usingPlacemarksArray:(NSArray *)placemarks {


self.coords =  mapView.userLocation.coordinate;


// Set the size of the region we want to get search results for.
MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.001250, 0.001250);
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(mapView.userLocation.coordinate, span);   

[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];



// Create the search request
self.localSearchRequest = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
self.localSearchRequest.region = region;
self.localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = searchString;

// Perform the search request...
self.localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:self.localSearchRequest];
[self.localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    if(error){

        NSLog(@"localSearch startWithCompletionHandlerFailed!  Error: %@", error);
        return;

    } else {

        // We are here because we have data!

        for(MKMapItem *mapItem in response.mapItems){

            // Show pins...

            NSMutableArray *annotations = [NSMutableArray array];


            Annotation *annotation = [[Annotation alloc] initWithCoordinate: mapItem.placemark.location.coordinate];
            annotation.title = mapItem.name;
            annotation.subtitle = mapItem.placemark.addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
            [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
            NSLog(@"Name for result: = %@", mapItem.name);

              [self.mapView addAnnotations:annotations];

                NSLog(@"Name for result: = %@", mapItem.name);


        }

        MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01);
        MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(self.coords, span);
        [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];


    }
}];


         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had set my custom annotation to be a subclass of NKPlacemark....I needed to have it be a subclass of NSObject.